# Can't get printTimeLineItemMetadata to pass variables outside of the function

Tags: php, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Hello I've been trying to get the mirror api to check if a timeline item has been deleted and if so create a new one if not update the old one. I am programming in php and I know this seems like it should be fairly straight forward but for some reason I'm stuck! Please help!
Right now I have it setup like so and it doesn't seem to want to pass the variable outside of the function and I can't do an insert from inside of the function either.

```
function printTimelineItemMetadata($service, $itemId) {
try {
$timelineItem = $service->timeline->get($itemId);

print 'Timeline item ID: ' . $timelineItem->getId();
if ($timelineItem->getIsDeleted()) {
  $deleted = "deleted";
  echo $deleted;

}
else { $deleted = "nope";
echo $deleted;}
 } catch (Exception $e) {
print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

I can get $deleted to echo in both cases but once I try and pass $deleted to a if statement further down below it won't take.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're observing. Can you edit the question and add an example of the output that's printed on the screen when you run it?

Comment: Just ignore me I'm an idiot and needed to make $deleted a global variable

Answer (score 0):

As the question asker explained in a comment on the question, this has to do with scoping. Functions in PHP have their own scope, so variables that were defined in a function by default do not exist outside of that function.

The quick-fix to this is to make the variable `global`, but having to use many global variables is usually poor software design. If you find yourself in this situation, try rethinking your code to make it more modular.